# How to detect and a post call converted to get using Burp Interceptor

Tags: java, post, methods, get

For one my client i am fixing one security issue where a hacker is changing request method from POST to GET. Can anyone tell me how I can detect such scenario on server side?
Server needs to serve both GET and POST requests but it needs to restrict those GETs which are originally POST and were converted to GETby hacker.

Comment: Is your server side code stateful? (does it expect requests to come in a certain sequence?). Does the request still have valid data after the interception but only with changed request type?

Comment: yes the server expect the request in certain sequences. and Data is valid after the interception but its open to security attack.